# Arquillian and wildfly 10 - Cannot undeploy: 144976d2-382b-438f-8b8a-2007db7b53c2.war

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm running integration tests from MVN with Wildfly 10 and Arquilliain.  I get the following error:

> WARN  ArchiveDeployer - Cannot undeploy:
>   144976d2-382b-438f-8b8a-2007db7b53c2.war
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper$ServerDeploymentException:
>   java.lang.Exception: "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource
>   '[(\"deployment\" => \"144976d2-382b-438f-8b8a-2007db7b53c2.war\")]'
>   not found"    at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.undeploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.undeploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:55)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.undeploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:152)
>     at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$4.call(ContainerDeployController.java:205)
>     at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$4.call(ContainerDeployController.java:185)
>     at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)

Here's my Arquillian (identical to another project that works, so I don't think this is the issue, all the ports are right):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
  http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target</property>
    </engine>
<!--
    <container qualifier="wildfly-managed" default="true">
        <configuration>
            &lt;!&ndash;            <property name="serverConfig">standalone.xml</property> Does not work, use -DjbossHome=.....&ndash;&gt;
            <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>

            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100</property>
            <property name="managementPort">10090</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
-->
    <container qualifier="wildfly-remote" default="true">
        <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
            <property name="host">192.168.3.70</property>
            <property name="port">8180</property>
        </protocol>
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementPort">10090</property>
            <property name="username">mike</property>
            <property name="password">mike</property>
            <property name="managementAddress">192.168.3.70</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

    <extension qualifier="transaction">
        <property name="manager">java:jboss/UserTransaction</property>
    </extension>

</arquillian>
```

My deployment is built like so:

```
@Deployment
  public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    WebArchive wa = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addPackage(Baby.class.getPackage())
        .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
        .addAsManifestResource("jboss-deployment-structure.xml", "jboss-deployment-structure.xml")
        .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
        .addAsResource("arquillian.xml", "arquillian.xml").addAsResource("log4j.xml", "log4j.xml")
        .addAsLibrary(Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").resolve("joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3")
            .withTransitivity().asSingleFile())
        .addAsLibraries((Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
            .resolve("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:2.7.4").withTransitivity()
            .asFile()));
```

The app works fine, and if I launch it as a managed container on a local WF installation it works.  For some reason, the remote container is failing.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I also added this to web.xml and it did not change the issue:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>antiJARLocking</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>antiResourceLocking</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I am encountering the same issue... when I have a wildfly where the war is deployed it works, but on the CI I want to use a fresh wildfly with no deployment and therefore it is clear, that the undeployment can not work. Is there an option to not fail for arquillian if there is no war to undeploy? Just undeploy if there is a war, if undeploy fails just continue with deployment

Comment: actually I found out that the warning of the not working undeployment was not the problem and that the arquillian continues deploying the war... there was another problem afterwards